# Is there a name for this type of transition probability diagram which seems not to be a transition probability graph?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

This is a "transition probability graph" coming from the book "Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition by Dimitri P. Bertsekas and John N. Tsitsiklis".

[image]

That book also gives this figure,

[image]

which seems not to be a transition probability graph.

Is there a name for this type of transition probability diagram?

Comment: Please tell us what this book's definition of "transition probability graph is."  BTW, there must be hundreds of books with this title: who are the authors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a more general sense, it can be classified as a DAG, or directed acyclic graph. It is a finite graph, it is directed since the edges of the graph have a direction and it is acyclical (loosely speaking, there are is no way to start at one point of the graph and loop back to it following the direction of the edges). This last point is due to the fact that "time" flows in only one direction.

Note how graph 7.5 is by all means a representation of 7.4 over several times.